# php loop mysql only executing once

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

** ANSWERED .. Was whitespace after commas.  Thanks everyone!

When I execute the following code, all $castmember are displayed however mysql is only run on the first one.

```
   $getactors=explode(",", $actors);
   foreach($getactors as $castmember){

     $idolid="";
     $srch3= "SELECT `id`,`dir` FROM `idols` WHERE `name`='$castmember'";
     $result5 = mysql_query($srch3);
     while ($row5 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result5)) {
     $idolid = $row5["id"];
     $idoldir= $row5["dir"];
     }

   if($idolid){ echo"<li style=\"font-size:1.2em;\" ><a href=\"/gallery/$idolid/$idoldir.html\" title=\"$castmember\" itemprop=\"actors\"> $castmember</a>";
     } else {
   echo"<li style=\"font-size:1.2em;\"><div style=\"display:inline\" itemprop=\"actors\"> $castmember</div>";
     }
   echo"<span></span></li>\n";
   }
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: **mysql is only run on the first one.** explain this line in more detail.

Comment: Do a `var_dump` on `$getactors`, is it the array you expect?  If it is iterating more than once with the foreach, the issue might be the value in the where clause has some extra whitespace and the SQL returns no results.  Could just echo `$srch3` in the loop to see what your building out.

Comment: if $actors has more than one actor in it, mysql is only being run on the first actor returned from the explode.  None of the others ever return an $idolid.

Comment: And if a value in `$getactors` includes an apostrophe, for example, the unescaped query will be broken.

Comment: You must at least `$castmember = mysql_real_escape_string($castmember);` Otherwise Mr. O'Reilly will break your query.

Comment: well i feel stupid.  It was whitespaces after the comma.  Used trim() to clean them up.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: don't use the mysql extension, it is deprecated and NOT recommended, i know its not really related to your issue (thats why i write it in the comments) but please use mysqli or pdo.
Also i'd like to know what the output IS and what you EXPECT it to be?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `explode` and then run query in loop. You can use `IN` clause.

```
 $srch3= "SELECT `id`,`dir` FROM `idols` WHERE `name` IN ('".$actors."')";
```

This will work only if your `$actors` array has valid values though.